# Recognise fields from identity card

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

The question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684190/how-to-read-words-from-identity-card-using-tesseract-ocr) and the commercial solution from BlinkID is working well for me.

I am trying to extend the application to recognise more type of document. For the moment I am using Google Cloud Vision with a [Bigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram) algorithm to (heuristic) detect the keyword (`Nom`, `Prénom`, `Née` etc) but the result is not optimal: sometimes the fields are in the same paragraph, sometimes not; some keywords art too short (`à`) and not always visible etc.

Having no background in computer vision, I'm looking for a way to improve the current solution or a better one.

[image]

Comment: Which method are you using for recognition? I have tested some pictures with [`DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#try_it) and the result was pretty good (regardless that `à` has been recognized as `1` but I think it could be easily replaced with some program).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @enle lin. I do use DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION; the text is well recognised, what I am interested in is how to detect fields. For the moment, I'm trying to detect keywords, I'm also thinking of normalising the position on the card itself (the size is well-known) but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it.